# MEF exports that require remote data (like DB data) in order to be created

Tags: mef, factory-pattern

please excuse the long description at the beginning. the questions are at the end.

i have a windows service that is supposed to read data form some data sources (represented by the IDataSource interface).

i'm using MEF in my project and i was thinking of injecting the required data sources via ctor injection like below:

```
[Export(typeof(Service))] 
public class Service:ServiceBase{
     [ImportingConstructor] 
     public Service([ImportMany]IEnumerable<IDataSource> dataSources){
         //...
     }
}
```

However, there is a problem in doing it like this. The service needs to use any combination of data sources: multiple data sources of the same type (ex: 2 CSVDataSource instances) or multiple data sources of different types (ex: 2 CSVDataSource instances and 1 SQLDataSource instance).

Each data source has properties that are retrieved from the DB in order to properly set it up. these settings might indicate from where to read the data and at what intervals. this is why, in my implementation, the data sources have a ctor that accepts an id. this id is used to identify the data source in the DB and to retrieve the specific data source settings from the DB. this can be seen below.

```
public class CSVDataSource: IDataSource{
    public CSVDataSource(int dsId){
        //call web service in order to get properties to
        //properly set up the data source.
    }
    //...
}
```

i feel that the service definition presented above is not suited for this scenario. The other approach I can think of is to use some sort of factory that allows the service to dynamically create the data sources inside. this implementation might look like below.

```
public class Service:ServiceBase{
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public Service(IDataSourceFactory dsFactory)
        {
            if (dsFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dsFactory");
            IEnumerable<IDataSource> dataSources = dsFactory.CreateAll();
        }
    }

[Export(typeof(IDataSourceFactory))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public class DataSourceFactory:IDataSourceFactory
    {
        private readonly int agentId;
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public DataSourceFactory([Import("AgentId")]int agentId)
        {
            this.agentId = agentId;
        }
        public IEnumerable<IDataSource> CreateAll()
        {
            List<IDataSource> dataSources = new List<IDataSource>();
            //access web service and instantiate the data sources
            return dataSources;
        }
    }
```

And now to my questions:

1. is my factory approach a good ideea or should i look for another approach?
2. is it ok to have exports that require data from a remote location in order to be created?

Answer (score 0):

Did you come across ExportMetadataAttribute before? It will allow you to assign metadata to an export that you can view before the export is created. You'll be able to import your IDataSources as Lazy and then should be able to create them yourself with the required parameters.

There's a good breakdown of Lazy and ExportMetadata [here](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/06/mef-or-managed-extensibility-framework.html)

Comment: my goal is to create IDataSource instances. For this i require some ids from the database. The ExportMetadata can store extra data that is specified at compile time. this data allows me to distinguish between exports. i'm not sure this solution applies in my case.this is why: i have 2 modules (one CSV and one SQL). i need 2 CSV instances and 1 SQL instance. how will i specify the export metadata in this case?

Comment: Ahh my mistake, I thought your ids for the IDataSource instances were hardcoded. As you noticed, ExportMetadata won't work in this case.